# Having difficulties installing Bellatrix on Windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, pip

I have installed Bellatrix on my Windows machine using `pip install bellatrix`. However, when I try to execute any command, such as `bellatrix list`, I get the error `'bellatrix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

here is the Bellatrix author. I just saw this question (you should have email-me first ;) )

Bellatrix has been extensively used in Linux / Unix / Mac but not so much in Windows. I know from one user who has blogged about his experience on Windows: http://mainlydata.kubadev.com/ec2/bellatrix-windows-users-two-things-to-remember/

Anyway, I just released 1.1.10 which comes with a nice Windows bridge so you will be able to use the same commands seamlessly in Windows.

In order to install or upgrade to the new version, just type:

```
pip install bellatrix --upgrade
```

Let me know if you have any problem.